# Android Launcher Application keeps being destroyed

Tags: android, android-webview, launcher

I'm developing custom launcher app containing a WebView. When I launch app as a normal app, it works without any issues, after calling startActivity()/ startActivityForResult() (Intent.ACTION_CALL, doesn't occur when using Intent for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) application calls onPause(), onStop() and other activity starts, after completing its task goes back to the application. However when I set application as launcher, it calls onDestroy() right after onPause() and onStop(). Such behaviour is not desired because I'm trying to keep inserted data in the launcher WebView app.

There are also many errors in logcat right after onDestroy() similar or same as E/libGLESv2﹕ HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES3-glDeleteBuffers (when not using it as launcher such errors appear, but sporadically and in different situations).

AppManifest contains

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I also tried using singleInstance, with that mode application works correctly after installation, but breaks its behaviour after restart.

Using minSdkVersion 19, tested on Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's how I managed to solve the issue, and actually what was the problem. I used

```
    Settings.System.putInt(
            getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.USER_ROTATION,
           // toRotate //Or a different ROTATION_ constant
            Surface.ROTATION_270
    );
```

for screen rotation, because I needed to be sure the app was running in landscape mode. The thing is, camera supports landscape mode, but dialer doesn't. So when I launched camera it was without issues, but dialer caused portrait rotation and that caused WebView's default behaviour when rotating the screen, onDestroy() and that causes reload afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Let begin by changing it to something like this,

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now lets understand what *launchMode(s)* are

via the documentation:

> android:launchMode
> **An instruction on how the activity should be launched.  There are four modes that work in conjunction with activity flags
> (FLAG_ACTIVITY_* constants) in Intent objects to determine what should
> happen when the activity is called upon to handle an intent. They are:
> "standard"  "singleTop"  "singleTask"  "singleInstance" The default
> mode is "standard".**
>
> **"singleTask"** *Does not allow* **Multiple** Instances The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent
> to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the
> system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its
> onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.
>
> "**standard**" Default. The system always creates a new instance of
> the activity in the target task and routes the intent to it.
>
> "**singleTop**" If an **instance** of the activity *already* exists at
> the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that
> instance through a call to its **onNewIntent**() method, rather than
> creating a new instance of the activity.
>
> **singleInstance**" Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the
> instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its
> task.

For more in depth refer to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Thank you, this works, but it as soon as I use  `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` it starts to call onDestroy() again, onNewIntent() is never called according to logcat. I just don't get it, it works ok when starting Camera activity, but it is broken when starting Dial activity.